# Convert Unix epoch timestamp to MySQL timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, unix, timestamp

I have an issue whereby a client has some legacy environment (IIS 6 / PHP 5.0.1) and keeps getting the following error:

> Warning: date() [function.date]: Windows does not support dates prior to midnight (00:00:00), January 1, 1970 in" when using the date() function.

I need to find a way to convert my UNIX timestamp, i.e "1293559200" (28th of Dec, 2010) to something I can then pass on as a correct date.

Comment: Does he get this error for pre-1970 dates (i.e. negative timestamp?) Which PHP and IIS version is that?

Comment: What version of PHP? Since 5.1.0, PHP on Windows has supported signed 32-bit dates from 13th Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to 19th Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT

Comment: Version 5.0.1. So you're saying if the client upgrades, he'll be a unix timestamp (i.e. 1293559200 ) via the date() function on an IIS server? Thank you!

Comment: PHP 5.0.1 // Microsoft-IIS/6.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Where you can replace UNIX_TIMESTAMP() with your timestamp value.