# Convert unix epoch timestamp to TSQL datetime

Tags: t-sql, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have found only [one similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794162/convert-unix-epoch-timestamp-to-mysql-timestamp-in-php) but for MySQL.

I was working on a web service and had to query the database (MS SQL server). Since I couldn't get the right result I decided to test the query via a SQL client. The web service uses Hibernate to access the DB and all time values are always represented as long values (unix epoch time). In order to test it, I needed to convert the unix timestamp to TSQL timestamp. This is what I came up with:

```
select dateadd(ms,123,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.0');
```

which outputs:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.123
```

But, my actual data was a bit bigger

```
select dateadd(ms,1359016610667 ,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.0');
```

which outputs:

```
Error code 0, SQL state 22001: Data truncation
Error code 8115, SQL state 22003: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

So, I tried:

```
select dateadd(ms,CAST (1359016610667 AS BIGINT) ,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.0');
```

which outputs the exact same error. Just to be safe I tried:

```
select CAST (1359016610667 AS BIGINT)
```

which outputs:

```
1359016610667
```

I made sure that [java long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) is equivalent to [TSQL bigint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) - they are both `8 B` long. Rereading the [dateadd() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) revealed the following:

> DATEADD (datepart , number , date ) 
>   ....
>   number 
>   Is an expression that can be **resolved to an int** that is added to a datepart of date. User-defined variables are valid.

If I understand this correctly, it means that this approach can not be used to convert a unix timestamp to TSQL timestamp, which is, well, pardon my language, but just plain stupid.

My questions are:

- is my interpretation of this situation correct?
- is there any other **one-liner** to do this conversion in TSQL ?

PS
modifying the date argument (`'1970-01-01 00:00:00.0'`) is not acceptable as solution. I'm debugging and I don't want to recalculate the miliseconds along :)

Comment: will the downvoter kindly explain why the question was downvoted?

Comment: LoL, again? well, see the upper comment...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Easy, first add whole days, then add the remaining ms. There are 86,400,000 milliseconds in a day.

```
declare @unixTS bigint
set @unixTS = 1359016610667


select dateadd(ms, @unixTS%(3600*24*1000), 
    dateadd(day, @unixTS/(3600*24*1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0')
)
```

The result is `2013-01-24 08:36:50.667`

Comment: The result is 2013-01-24 08:36:50.667, but in which timezone? UTC?

Comment: @luisdev If the input unix timestamp is in UTC, the result will be in UTC. If not, then not.

Answer (score 13):

This should work perfect for those long epoch times.

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 1359016610667 / 1000, '19700101 00:00')
```

Comment: This method of just adding seconds, rather than both milliseconds and days (as the answer from @ben) causes an arithmetic overflow error when working with dates like '31 December 2099' when SQL tries to convert the number of seconds to add into an int.

Comment: This results in the Y2038 bug. The `number` parameter is an integer so adding seconds like this can only go up to 2038-01-19