# Displaying SQL Column in date format from bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I display SQL column in date format which is in bigint?

I am not looking to convert each row for example

```
select dateadd(second, 1358523245140/1000+8*60*60,  '19700101') from tablename
```

Comment: then what are you looking to?

Comment: hago. What I want is an automated sql query which displays all rows within the bigint column in date format. currently, I am running the table then picking each row and converting it individually like above. Hope this makes sense. So should I create procedure within select statement. If yes, then I am looking at an example as to how I can insert the above within the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

To display in a recognizable date format just add the desired format style on top of that calculation. e.g.

```
select
    dateadd(second, 1358523245140/1000+8*60*60,  '19700101') 
  , convert(varchar, dateadd(second, 1358523245140/1000+8*60*60,  '19700101') ,121)
;
```

The first column will display in the database default format (e.g. January, 18 2013 23:34:05+0000) , the second column will display is style 121 (2013-01-18 23:34:05.000)

There are many tables of these styles available, or in SQL 2012 you can use the FORMAT()

e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2012/format-function-vs-convert-function.aspx

ps: there is another method for converting that 13 digit unix timestamp to TSQL datetime here:
[Convert unix epoch timestamp to TSQL timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507649/convert-unix-epoch-timestamp-to-tsql-timestamp)

Comment: by the way, I assume that when you sat "I am not looking to convert" you mean you don't want to change the column to datetime or add another column. (but: It would be possible to use a computed column so you don't have to do this for each query)

Comment: Thank you. So should I use the above select statement within the procedure? currently, I run the table and pick values each time (example, 1358523245140) then convert it. I want to display it for all rows in one query. Also, these values are 18 in number and I reduce it to 13 everytime.

Comment: 1358523245140 is originally 135852324514000000

Comment: your question isn't very detailed - you may want to edit it? there was no mention of procedure or truncation of field for example - so it was a guess on what you really wanted. Seems like yo are working through a cursor so I'm not sure what you really want now. You may use a query like I proposed but how it sits with a proc I've never seen I don't know. Sorry.